# Automatically downloading files from a specific website

Tags: asp.net, unix, cron, screen-scraping, scheduled-tasks

I am a very new programmer.. A website is providing a lot of zip files that i needed. It will be updated/uploaded new zip files weekly. What I need to do is write a program/script to do auto downloading from the web weekly..  for example, this is the web link http://www.google.com/googlebooks/uspto-patents-applications-yellowbook.html ( you can see a lot of zip files there )

so my question is

1. What script i have to write(i got no experience in writing any script, so what can you suggest?) so i can download the zip file programmatically?
2. If the 1st questioned solved, then how should i make it to download the new zip file uploaded weekly?

Is it i have to use DOM...unix? if yes, i will do some research on tat to make it work.

Comment: Do the names of the zip files change each week, or are they constant?

Comment: DOM has nothing to do with UNIX.

Comment: thx for the replied, drlouie and Michael... http://www.google.com/googlebooks/uspto-patents-applications-yellowbook.html , as the link, u can see the zip files there.. the name will be changed based on the date it uploaded..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wget? You can use HtmlAgilityPack to parse the website and extract all links. Then you simply loop over all urls and download the file, using C# all the way through. You can also open a wget process from c# if you wish to do so.

On the other hand, this can easily be done using bash and sed/awk and grep in combination with wget.

Either way you will still need cron to schedule the job on a weekly basis.

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient ();
Client.DownloadFile("http://www.csharpfriends.com/Members/index.aspx", "index.aspx");
```

Comment: There's a windows port (cronw.sourceforge.net), but why not just use Windows' scheduler when you are on Windows ?

Answer (score 1):

I've also used JSoup (http://jsoup.org/) very effectively in Java/Scala applications to scrape data out of web pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux/UNIX, use 'wget' in a script for downloading the files, and 'cron' to schedule the downloading script.

Comment: The names are changing each week - screen scraping will also be involved to get a list of links wont it?

Comment: It can but you'll need to build a list of URLs you want to `wget` first.

Comment: Michael, is it I have to use UNIX in order to make wget work? i cant use windows?